# Why MSB is discarded in case of bits overflow?

Tags: c, char, unsigned, bit

Take `unsigned char` for example.

Its range is `0 to 255`.

If I try to store `256` in it, following will happen :-

Binary of `256`

> 100000000

As it consists of `9-bits` hence MSB `1` will be discarded and it will become

> 00000000

Which is `0`.

So I want to know that why only left most bit is removed?

Comment: [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: @devnull : I think 2's compliment is used in case of negative numbers...And I am talking about `unsigned char` not `signed char`

Comment: You'll find your answer __if__ you were to read the linked page.

Comment: OP, What alternative would you propose? Eg, what would you like to happen if someone tried to store 256 in an 8 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: @SchighSchagh : I am not against the current rule. I am just asking the reason for that.

Comment: "why only left most bit is removed?" - cause it is the one that causes the overflow, i.e. there is no room for him => discard him.

Comment: @Dabo : if right-most bit is removed then also it will turn to 8-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's the most reasonable & useful thing that could happen when you only have 8 bits of space.

Discarding the *lowermost* bit would be a bad idea because now you can no longer increment the integer to get the next integer mod 2<sup>8</sup>, etc... it would become useless as soon as it overflowed.
Discarding any other bit in the middle would be bizarre, and any other kind of awkward transformation would effectively border on insanity.

Comment: `Discarding the lowermost bit would be a bad idea because now you can no longer increment the integer.`. how?

Comment: It actually has useful mathematical properties (modular arithmetic). All other possibilities would have essentially no useful mathematical properties.

Comment: @kevingomes: Sorry that was confusing. You could truncate it and add 1, sure, but I meant you couldn't increment the *value* for any sane definition of "increment"; it would end up being n/2 + 1 which is not called "incrementing" n and is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

The reason only the lowest 8 bits can be kept in the result is that the significance of each bit is constant: bit 0 is the ones place, bit 1 is the twos place, bit 2 is the fours place, etc. There is no way to "change" what any of these bits means without additional storage. Floating point, where you might (this is just a guess on my part) be getting your expectation that something else could happen has storage for an exponent, so that the significance of each bit in the significand can vary depending on the magnitude of the value you want to store. The important thing to realize is that this variation itself takes storage (in the form of the exponent) and cannot happen in an integer/fixed-point type where each bit has a particular fixed meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of this would be if you had 8 decimal digits with which to represent a number.  In this case, we could represent `100,000,000` values, ranging from `00,000,000` to `99,999,999`.  As we counted up, we would have:

```
00,000,000
00,000,001
00,000,002
00,000,003

...

99,999,997
99,999,998
99,999,999
???
```

Since we don't have another digit to represent `100,000,000`, what is the best course of action?  We can't keep incrementing to `100,000,000` because that would require another digit we don't have.  To make this work, we'd have to drop the `1` at the left side and get `00,000,000`.  This is still meaningful if we keep in mind that this number now represents `100,000,000` + whatever its value is.  In this way, you can keep counting and the value remains at least somewhat meaningful:

```
99,999,998
99,999,999
00,000,000 represents 100,000,000
00,000,001 represents 100,000,001
00,000,002 represents 100,000,002
...
```

If we instead dropped the least significant digit (the 0 on the right), we would have:

```
99,999,998
99,999,999
10,000,000 ???
10,000,001 ???
```

There's no point in continuing to count because our number doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the left-most bit, you have an 8-bit number and it can fit properly in a byte (unsigned char).  It wouldn't make sense to remove more than one bit because you don't need to do that to reduce that particular number down to 8 bits.  Only the lowest 8 bits can be kept when storing a value in an unsigned char.

Comment: That's what I am asking. Why only lowest 8 bits can be kept?

Comment: See my answer; hopefully it addresses your question in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

C is a low level language, which maps closely to actual hardware. Underneath the type `char`, there is an assumption that the CPU has an 8-bit register, consisting of fixed amount of transistors and wires.

As the computer can't grow the number of physical resources, the type `char` is chosen to represent integers *modulo* 256.

On a computer architecture, where the primitive resource is an 9-bit unit, char holds 9 bits.

High level languages, which are often interpreted, OTOH can and do often "grow" the variable width.

Answer (score 0):

`So I want to know that why only left most bit is removed?`

It's really not a question of "only the **left most** bit being *removed*"...it's that the **eight right-most** bits are *preserved*.  If not the eight right-most bits, then which bits do YOU think should be preserved?  You can't keep all nine-bits, it's only an 8-bit value!